# gcloud and gsutil blob download is slow inside cloud run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-run

All i want is download 1 GB file as fast as possible.

I have below cloudrun configuration:
cpu 8
memory 16 GB

dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.10-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./


RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl


# Downloading gcloud package
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz

# Installing the package
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet

# Adding the package path to local
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin

# Remove gz file
RUN rm -f /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz

# Install crcmod this is require for sliced download from gcloud
#RUN apt-get -y install gcc python3-dev python3-setuptools
RUN pip uninstall crcmod
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U crcmod


# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 8 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Bucket is in us multi-region.
cloud run is in us-central1

Average download throughput never crossing above 70 MB / s
takes around 13 seconds to download file of 1GB file.

On the other hand on cloud shell or physical machine download speed crossing 100 MBPS. around 6 to 7 seconds for 1 GB file.

i tried many options with gsutil to tune sliced download on cloudrun its not working.

Expert could you help me on getting more download speed on cloud run at least same as cloud shell (4 cpu, us-cental1)

running below commands inside cloud run container to test speed:

1. transfer_manager.download_chunks_concurrently(blob, filepath, max_workers=8)
2. os.system('curl “s”signed url of file  -o /tmp/sampeFile')
3. 

```
cmd = ["gcloud", "storage", "cp", "gs://" + bucket_name + '/' + path_name, tmp_download_path]

# This is asynchronus call
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, close_fds=False)
rc=sp.wait()
```

4. gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1" -o   "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=8" -o   cp sourceblob /tmp/destination

Nothing speeds up (> 13 sec time for all above examples)

Something wrong with my dockerfile or cloud run wont support fast download. Help!

Comment: Can you try to set the min instance to 1, or to deactivate the CPU Throttling on Cloud Run? Or share more piece of code to let us know if you are send the file inside or outside the request context.

Comment: i already tried with "CPU is always allocated" and for sure i am downloading file in request context (its not background task).  i am waiting if i used subprocess ..and in os.system() its already sync call.

Comment: The overhead of launching the Python environment to run the CLI (gsutil/gcloud) is too high for a small download of 1 GB. Python is interpreted and the CLI is large. It would be better to write code using the raw HTTP REST API. If the file does not change often, I would just include the file it in the container image. When the file changes, push a new container image. Google has stated that container image size does not affect cold start time for Cloud Run (managed) so that would give you the fastest possible cold start time with no download overhead.

Comment: I am not counting time require to  launching the Python environment to run the CLI. I used python client library there also i have same problem (same states). In our case file size can be large than 1GB , and  File changes frequently. or can receive new files.

Comment: @JohnHanley
Does this 32 MB  response limit of cloud run has to do something around giving same (low) average download speed across client libraries. ?
should i change docker image from python-slim to full flesh OS image. ?

Sorry to ask dumb thing but i stuck in this use case so badly , If it wont work i have to switch away from cloud run. I am not getting any ans from github/stack overflow/ google forum. Help me to take it to conclusion.

Comment: The 32 MB limitation is for HTTP request bodies sent to Cloud Run, not for requests sent from Cloud Run. Changing the base image will not have a measurable difference. Your problem is that you are not being realistic with performance expectations. For your previous question, I commented that 100 MB/sec is enterprise performance. That is for real hardware and virtual machines. Those numbers are not realistic for serverless container services that are not optimized for raw network performance. The hardware is being shared among hundreds/thousands of containers. That is reflected in the low price